# Ckeditor Inline Editing - hyperlinks don't work

Tags: ckeditor

Hyperlinks don't work when applying inline editing to a div tag.

You can even try it on this online [DEMO](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline).

1. Insert Hyperlink
2. Disable inline edit dialog by clicking somewhere on the page
3. Try to click on created hyperlink. Hyperlink hand cursor doesn't appear as you normal would expect when pressing link in a webpage.

Destroying CKeditor instance will also not resolve this problem.

Is this normal behavior ?

Comment: This is fine. Even though an instance is destroyed, the element still has `contenteditable="true"` [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html#contenteditable0) (inspect the code). Browsers assume that such element is for creating contents but not for navigation, unless you remove the attribute.

Comment: @oleq Can i remove 'contenteditable="true' on the fly by using jquery?
I have used this code, but this was not successful '$("#editable").removeAttr("contenteditable");' => Hyperlinks are still not working

Comment: `$('#editable').attr('contenteditable', 'false');` would be better.

Comment: Get element: `var element = CKEDITOR.instances.instance.element;`, 
destroy editor: `CKEDITOR.instances.instance.destroy();`,
remove attribute: `element.removeAttribute( 'contenteditable' );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behavior, you're in an editing mode.

Inline editing was made for a back-end use, you're not suppose to click on those hyperlinks like a front-end user. You just have to display the generated HTML in a front-end div (without CKEditor, of course) to get your hyperlinks work.

Comment: Suppose i want to create a small CMS application.
User can modify the content which has been included inside a div with attribute 'contenteditable' set to true.
This data can be stored somewhere in the backend, but how should i display this content?
It would be ideal if you could remove the CKeditor instance or related attributes of div on the fly after use has pressed the save button in Ckeditor. Another button will activate the editor again......

Comment: You've got an user-action to enter/leave the edit mode (a button pressed). Then I would suggest you to reload the page when entering/leaving this mode. In this case, you can enable or not CKEditor, and avoid edit mode's scripts to be executed. Moreover, you can easily manage the permissions on the edit mode

Comment: All text editors, from gmail to Ms Word, allow to open links. -1

Answer (score 1):

To open the link in inline editing mode, just CTRL + click, like in MS Word, but not with IE.